# AWS EC2 create Instances Dynamically

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to build a Platform, with AWS, which calculates Simulations.

Some of them need more CPUs and RAM, so i need to have a bigger Instance.
As the bigger Instances are more expensive I don't want to have them up and running all the time.

My approach is to start a Instance with my own AMI if i need it and delete it afterwards.

Is this a good Idea or are there better solutions for that Issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What J. Meijers said, and also if your application can tolerate occasional loss of an instance and can reschedule jobs easily, you can save a lot of money using [spot instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/) instead of on-demand.

When you configure your [autoscaling group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/GettingStartedTutorial.html) you can set it to use spot instances and if you lose instances due to price spike, they'll come right back once the price drops.

Autoscaling group is convenient even if you only want to run one large instance. You can manually "scale" it to zero when you don't need it and back to 1 when you have work to do and the instance will come right back. Autoscaling group costs nothing while there's no instance running in it.

You can supplement whatever AMI you use by including a [user_data.sh script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) in your launch config. Those are commands that will be run on any instance when it is created.

Make sure you specify an [IAM role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) for your ASG launch config. You'll be happy you did later.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at autoscaling groups, that scale based on certain metrics. You will need to make sure that your application can be scaled horizontally though